# Are there exotic versions of back gear?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So far the best gear I found for that slot would be from the guild armorer, which cost 5g for the level 80 rare version. Any idea if there are other sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Lost Shores update, you can find Green, Blue, and Yellow Back Slot items as regular drops, and not just from your personal story quest.

In addition, Exotic and Ascended Backpieces are available to those who spend their time delving into the Fractals and dropping bundles of goods into the Mystic Forge.

The exotic pieces can be bought with Fractal Relics alone, but to reach ascended, you'll need a lot of stuff! [This page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vial_of_Condensed_Mists_Essence) has more info.

Comment: Thanks. Seems pretty weird that they will release a type of gear without any exotic variants for now.

Comment: @TerryChia It's more that the slot just doesn't have any base stats at all. You can still throw in an exotic jewel or rune in there.

Comment: As of the Halloween event and the introduction of the Fractal dungeons, there are now new back items that have stats on them.

Comment: As of the Escape from Lion's Arch Living Story arc, there is a "craftable" [upgrading backpiece](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Spinal_Blade_Pack). As of previous updates, there are also other ways of [mystic forging Ascended backpieces](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Piles_of_Bloodstone_Dust).

Answer (score -1):

You can buy the Lucky Great Ram Lantern for about 10 gold at the moment. With different stats to choose from.

Answer (score -2):

You can buy exotic back items for 42K Karma at any opened Orr temple.